# PHP Mysql - Delete button keeps on deleting latest row

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

When i run into a glitch, I always find find the answer on StackOverflow, but this time, although I'm sure the fix is easy, I just can't seem to get it right !

Basically, i'm trying to add a "delete" button next to each row fetched from my mysql database. The users should be able to delete a specific post, if needed.

When i hit the delete button, it's always the latest row  that gets deleted. So i guess there's something wrong with the value passed in each row : seems like they're overridden by the latest one.

Below's my code:

```
<?php  
$table = query("SELECT post, postid FROM post_list WHERE id = ? ORDER BY 
time DESC LIMIT 15", $_SESSION["id"]);
foreach ($table as $row) 
{ 
      $post = $row["post"];
      $postid = $row["postid"];  
      echo ("<table>");
      echo ("<tr>");
      echo("<td>" . $post . "</td>");
      echo("</td>")?>            
      <div id="posteraser">
       <form action='' method='post'>
          <input type='hidden' name='postid' value='<?php echo $postid?>'>
          <input type='submit' name='posteraser'>Delete</input>
       </form>
      </div>       
     <?php 
     echo ("</td>");
     echo ("</tr>");
     echo ("</table>");
     echo '<hr>';
}  
?>
```

And below on the same page, there's the delete button code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['posteraser']))
{
    $sql = query("DELETE FROM post_list WHERE postid = '$postid' ");       
    redirect ('home.php');
}
?>
```

Any help/tips will be much appreciated !
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I've never seen that type of syntax before. `echo ("...`. Something I don't know? `echo "(...)"` yes, but `("`? Bizarre.

Comment: `echo()` is fine, but unnecessary since it is a language construct

Comment: do print_r($_POST); in delete page. and verify what value is posting to next page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass here the `$_POST['postid']`

```
if(isset($_POST['posteraser'])){
   $postid = $_POST['postid'];
   $sql = query("DELETE FROM post_list WHERE postid = '$postid' ");       
   redirect ('home.php');
}
```

**OR** as procedure way

```
$sql = query("DELETE FROM post_list WHERE postid = ? ",$postid);
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks Yogesh, I knew i needed a pair of fresh eyes on this one!

Comment: @CharlieHarris strictly speaking, questions that require fresh eyes are against rules on Stack Overflow. The site is rather dedicated to knowledge, not sharp vision.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I completely agree with you. Based on the answers I got (yours included), I edited my code, so the flow of knowledge was 100% useful !

Answer (score 0):

A developer should always be aware **of the HTML code they create** with their PHP code.
It's **essential thing.**

As a matter of fact, HTML code is the very result of our efforts. NOT nice picture on can see in the browser windows - it's browser's job - but the very HTML code.

So, if you bother to see into generated code, you would discover something that can be boiled down to

```
<input type='hidden' name='postid' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='postid' value='3'>
<input type='hidden' name='postid' value='4'>
<input type='hidden' name='postid' value='5'>
<input type='hidden' name='postid' value='9'>
```

Do you have any questions why you have only last value?

Speaking of solutions, you have two choices

- create a separate form for the every row
- mark the very Delete button with id.

  ```
  <input type='submit' name='posteraser[<?php echo $postid?>]'>Delete</input>
  ```

  for example

Answer (score 0):

let's check the logic from select statement.
you are selecting postid and assigning it to a hidden element and when you press delete button
that hidden id is sent to server.
so form creating under for loop is

```
<div id="posteraser">
<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='postid' value='<?php echo $postid?>'>
  <input type='submit' name='posteraser'>Delete</input>
</form>
</div>
```

but hidden element is creating with same name for each row.
 so when you press delete button . first hidden id is sent to server.
 and this hidden id is already newest as from your select statement.

so what's the solution for it..
 either you should sent postid through get attaching it in your url so that you can identify
 which delete button is pressed.
 or create a logic to send only that id on which delete is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

This looks wrong:

```
echo ("<tr>");
echo("<td>" . $post . "</td>");
echo("</td>")?>
```

The trailing `</td>` shouldn't be there. Something else perhaps?

Also, you don't show how `postid` gets into `$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the delete functionality

Comment: Relax, it seems like otherwise. This comment is based on your answer posted yesterday talking about tds and trs, which do not have anything to do with the issue OP is facing. You did mention later what is the issue, but provided no answer to it, hence the comment

Comment: The answer was edited within 30 seconds of posting to include the postid issue.