# Mysql keep deleting wrong table row

Tags: php, mysql

User should be able to delete a specific row but the programs keep deleting first row. I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909914/php-mysql-delete-button-keeps-on-deleting-latest-row) Tried it did not work. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

**cart.php**

```
 <form id='updateCartForm' action="update_cart.php" method="get">
             <input name="cart_item_name" type = "hidden"  id ="cart_item_name" value='<?=$product['prod_name'];?>'>
 <input name="cart_item_id" type = "hidden"  id ="cart_item_id" value='<?=$product['id'];?>'>
 </form>
```

**update_cart.php**

```
<?php
require_once "core/db.php"

//get data from form
$cart_item_name = $_GET['cart_item_name'];
$cart_item_id = $_GET['cart_item_id'];

//execute query
$sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id =" .$cart_item_id;  
$db->query($sql);

//flash success message
$domain =($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $cart_item_name. ' was deleted from your cart.';
```

Comment: check the value you get in `$cart_item_id`. assume someone sends `cart_item_id` as `1;DROP TABLE cart;` Read a bit about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: @bansi he'd just have to send the value `id` and the whole table will be cleared, cause `id = id` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

**Is the design right?**
In your previous question also, I commented whether you have your design right. Using a product id as a cart item id as you are doing ehre does not make sense.

```
<form id='updateCartForm' action="update_cart.php" method="get">
             <input name="cart_item_name" type = "hidden"  id ="cart_item_name" value='<?=$product['prod_name'];?>'>
 <input name="cart_item_id" type = "hidden"  id ="cart_item_id" value='<?=$product['id'];?>'>
 </form>
```

Deleting using this cart_item_id would actually mean deleting all items in the cart from all users where the product is is $product['id']

That brings me to the second point. Why do you have both the product name and product id in the form? Only the product id is needed. Getting onto the delete.

Conclusion, you have the wrong table design or wrong query design.

**What's the first row?**

> the programs keep deleting first row.

There is no order by in your query. SO there is no such thing here as a first row. What's actually happening is probably what I have described in my first paragraph.

**SQL injection**
Now for a major security issue.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id =" .$cart_item_id;  
$db->query($sql);
```

This is a horrible way to do a query. You will some day find that not just one row but the whole database has been deleted. Read up on PDO prepared statements.

Comment: PHP and all other languages are tough; lots of headaches, but they're slowly growing on me

Comment: New to PHP? Hope what you are using is PDO and not mysqli. PDO is more versatile and can be used with databases other than mysql also. Saves you having to learn the postgresql/php interface, mssql/php interface and so on.

Comment: Yes I'm new. But, the design of the database is correct in my opinion, What you dont see here is that there's a query on the page that is Joining the product and the cart tables together which allows me to display the product information that are in the cart. So when I use $product['id] it is actually the cart_item_id (the cartRowId per se) BUT if I use $product['product_id'] this gives me the id of the product. That is why I'm confused as to why the wrong product gets deleted.

Comment: then the first thing you need is to read this  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and more importantly this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  peole make their conclusions on what you psot on your question and not on __what you don't see here__

Answer (score 0):

> Delete query will delete all rows if no **WHERE** clause is there,
>   otherwise it delete the rows matching with the **WHERE** caluse.

If it is not working as expected than put a check on variable that contains the id like:

```
echo $cart_item_id;
exit;
```

and see what it contains.

Answer (score -1):

Decided to go with the easier way using href.

**cart.php**

```
<a href="update_cart.php?productcartid=<?=$product['id'];?>">&times</a>
```

**update_cart.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'core/db.php';

//delete from cart

           $productcartid =$_REQUEST['productcartid'];

           // sending query
           $del = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id='$productcartid'";
           $db->query($del);
           header("Location: cart.php");
```

Comment: though it's your own answer it's wrong because youa re still leavng yourself wide open to sql injections.

Comment: @e4c5: Bro, apparently this is safe. I read about it right here on SO.

Comment: You have got that dead wrong. Not all stackoverflow answers are the same. Like for example you answer itself is wrong, likewise there willl be other answers here that are wrong. Just search for how do I prevent sql injection in PHP

Comment: @e4c5: I did have a read on [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) Im going to take care of security matter once the whole app works. Right now I've got to make everything runs first. I don't have that many scripts to look at so it's all good.

Comment: Once again, that's the wrong approach. That's duplicating data and there is always something that you miss. No please learn to do things right the first time.